# Stream of incoming values with many duplicates. How to detect change?

Tags: javascript

Values like these comes in as parameters into a function.

7,7,7,7,8,8,1,'peace',3,3,3,'love','love' and so on....

Need a logic that detects what's change and what's repetition.
Filter out repetitions.

EXAPMLE

```
setInterval(function(){

    post(url,data,callback(backfromserver){

        //every 5 seconds the function will be called with a parameter
        //this parameter will have many duplicates/repetitions
        //need to detect when something new happens
        //first approach: store/hold parameter for later comparison

        var store = backfromserver;
        if(backfromserver === store){
            //repetition
        }
        else{
            //new parameter to work with.
        }

        //but this if statement will always be true since i have to set it to the same to hold it.
        //how do you do it?
    });

},5000);
```

Comment: What do you mean "comes in one at a time into a function"?  Your question isn't clear, can you add details/source code examples of what you have tried?

Comment: The obvious answer would be to store the "last seen parameter" somewhere and check it before calling the actual function.

Comment: The point is to store the "last" value outside of the function, e.g. globally.

Comment: With your help I finally got it. Peace and Love

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take your store variable out of a function and assign it a *backfromserver* value, after you check if it's a repetition. Like this:

```
var store = null;    
setInterval(function(){

    post(url,data,callback(backfromserver){

        if(backfromserver === store){
            //repetition
        }
        else{
            //new parameter to work with.
        }
        store = backfromserver;

    });

},5000);
```

And remember, that if null is an allowed argument, than you have to assign sth else at the beginning or try another approach.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another option you can work from. I changed `setInterval` to a `setTimeout` because you have an inner asynchronous call (post) and you have a risk of intermingled answers if the post takes more then 5 seconds to answer. The  `setTimeout` solution will make sure that only one post is taking place at a given time.

```
var first = true;
var store;
var fetch = function(){
    post(url,data,function(err, res) {
      if(first || res !== store){
        first = false;
        store = res;
        // ..
        //new parameter to work with.
        // ..
      }
      else{
        // repetition
      }
      setTimeout(fetch, 5000);
    }
}
setTimeout(fetch, 0);
```

Comment: I get it, much better. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a fan of destructive assignment, so here's my go using the excellent [highland](http://highlandjs.org/) library by caolan. It works in the browser as well.

```
function createStream(url, data, interval) {
  return highland(function (push, next) {
    setInterval(function() {
      post(url, data, function (backFromServer) {
        push(null, backFromServer);
        next();
      });
    }, interval);
  });  
}

var stream = createStream(url, data, interval)
  .uniq()
  // alternatively use uniqBy
  // Now you can do something with these values or return the stream itself

// make sure to call this to start the stream.
stream.resume();
```

I haven't tested this, so the interaction between `post` and `highland` may not work perfectly but this should give you a good enough idea to get started with.